# How to revert a subversion ignore?

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, version-control

I've run the following command via commandline:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*.classpath" .
```

I wanted to only ignore the `.classpath` file.

However, this seems to have messed things up and now a lot of directories seem to be ignored.

How do I revert this and start over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**

For this svn:ignore you effectively said "ignore in the currect directory only files with extension classpath": patterns for filenames in Subversion uses only OS-specific glob-pattern, not regexps

**Fixes for syntax of DaFunix**

- List **all svn-properties and their values** in *somepath*: `svn proplist -v <PATH>|<URL>`. For your case

  svn proplist -v .

Sample output for my URL

```
>svn proplist -v http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/
Properties on 'http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk':
  bugtraq:logregex
    ([Ff][Ss])\s#
    (\d+)
  svn:mergeinfo
    /branches/Greetings:3-12
    /branches/i18n:18-20
```

- List **single svn:property value** (with known name): `svn propget <PROPERTY> <PATH>|<URL>`. For your case

  svn propget svn:ignore .

Sample output for my URL (same as before for proplist)

```
>svn propget bugtraq:logregex http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/
([Ff][Ss])\s#
(\d+)
```

Both proplist and propget operations are RO, will change nothing

**In order to fix bad definition of property you can**

or

Delete bad property and re-create it in correct form:

`svn propdel svn:ignore . & svn propset svn:ignore "classpath" .` (maybe use propset with -R option to define ignore resursively for the whole subtree)

or (as suggested by John Brodie) edit and fix current definition

`svn propedit svn:ignore .` and in editor window "*.classpath" change to "classpath", save

**PS** Don't forget:

- commit correct form of added property
- remove from versioned code previously (possibly) added classpath files: svn:ignore affect only unversioned new files, already added to repo files with current ignore-pattern must be unversioned by hand

Answer (score 13):

`svn propedit svn:ignore .` should bring up your editor, where you can remove the offending ignores one at a time.

Comment: it's worked with visual studio 2015 editor. just use `VisualSVN` then select `properties` and then delete rule.